# Count ratios conditional on 2 columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am new to pandas and trying to figure out the following how to calculate the percentage change (difference) between 2 years, given that sometimes there is no previous year.

I am given a dataframe as follows:

```
                company                   date                 amount
1           Company 1                    2020                 3
2           Company 1                    2021                 1
3           COMPANY2                     2020                 7
4           Company 3                    2020                 4
5           Company 3                    2021                 4
..                         ...            ...                          ...
766         Company N                    2021                 9
765         Company N                    2020                 1
767         Company XYZ                  2021                 3
768         Company X                    2021                 3
769         Company Z                    2020                 2
```

I wrote something like this:

```
for company in unique(df2.company): 
    company_df = df2[df2.company== company]
    company_df.sort_values(by ="date")
    company_df_year = company_df.amount.tolist()
    company_df_year.pop()
    company_df_year.insert(0,0)
    company_df["value_year_before"] = company_df_year
    if any in company_df.value_year_before == None: 
        company_df["diff"] = 0
    else:       
        company_df["diff"] = (company_df.amount- company_df.value_year_before)/company_df.value_year_before

df2["ratio"] = company_df["diff"]
```

But I keep getting >NAN.

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: A column of ratios would be great to have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that you are overwriting `company_df` in each iteration of the loop and only keeping the last one.

However, normally when using Pandas if you are starting to use a for loop then you are doing something wrong and there is an easier way to accomplish the goal. Here you could use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`pct_change`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.pct_change.html) to compute the ratio of each group.

```
df = df.sort_values(['company', 'date'])
df['ratio'] = df.groupby('company')['amount'].pct_change()
df['ratio'] = df['ratio'].fillna(0.0)
```

Groupby will keep the order of the rows within each group so we sort before to ensure that the order of the dates is correct and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) replace any nans with 0.

Result:

```
         company  date  amount     ratio
3       COMPANY2  2020       7  0.000000
1      Company 1  2020       3  0.000000
2      Company 1  2021       1 -0.666667
4      Company 3  2020       4  0.000000
5      Company 3  2021       4  0.000000
765    Company N  2020       1  0.000000
766    Company N  2021       9  8.000000
768    Company X  2021       3  0.000000
767  Company XYZ  2021       3  0.000000
769    Company Z  2020       2  0.000000
```

Comment: you reinvented `pct_change`. also `apply` is still looping but I understand the point (or do I?)

Comment: @doesitmatter: I was not aware of that function, thanks for pointing it out. I have updated the answer with this improvement. Yes, `apply` will act as a loop under the hood and is slow so using built-in functionality is always preferred when possible. However, `apply` is still better than a normal for loop such as in the question, both from a readability and number of lines perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Apply an anonymous function that calculate the change percentage and returns that if there is more than one values. Use:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'company': [1,1,3], 'date':[2020,2021,2020], 'amount': [4,5,7]})
 df.groupby('company')['amount'].apply(lambda x: (list(x)[1]-list(x)[0])/list(x)[0] if len(x)>1 else 'not enough values')
```

Input df:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Would you care to add an explanation of your code? Otherwise this will be a bit mysterious.